# Ionic 6 - Angular app - Android - UI jank, Slow rendering issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic6

I have Ionic 6 - Angular app deployed on Android that has a video player NGX Videogular embedded within it to play either downloaded videos or those from a CDN.

However, the UI janks after some time. I think Android simply freezes the UI frame. Only if I perform some action on the app like touching or scrolling the app, the video plays otherwise freezes up completely.

I am not an expert in Android or UI Jank debugging. With whatever I could search and come up, I was able to enable Hardware rendering on the device and started seeing UI debug bars within the app.

How do I do deeper analysis to find the issue within the app? Is there a tool I need to be aware of? I discovered UI Jank to be a possible cause only a few days ago.

Comment: NGX Videogular is the problem. You should try to find another video player.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for it? I will not be able to convince the product team otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried removing it yourself and see if thats your problem? You're describing your issue that sounds like its the video player problem.

Comment: I wonder how you arrived at your initial conclusion. With respect to your latest question, of course, I have tried everything, even changing the player from ngx-videogular to video.js and back.